# Excel - use both comma and dot to separate decimals

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have an Excel spreadsheet with some sort of generated data. This spreadsheet is then presented to a user who is supposed to fill in some numbers. Then there is a column with a simple sum of user inserted data.

The problem is that eventhough all of my users are in central Europe which uses comma(",") as a decimal separator, some of them still use dot(".") as a decimal separator. Excel then treats this cell as a datetime and there's no way user can switch cell format back to number (spreadsheet is password protected and most of cells are locked).

My question is: Is there a way to treat both dot and comma as a decimal separator? I can't use VBA and the column with a sum of user typed values has to be there (eg. converting cells to text won't help me, I guess, because sum does not work on text cells).

Comment: This spreadsheet is then automatically processed so I need to be sure that noone adds additional columns/cells and noone edits those already present (except the ones I need). I thought this can be done without using VBa and VBa and macros can be restricted by computer/domain admins

Comment: Pls provide some sample data to illustrate the problem

Comment: If you cannot educate your users regarding proper data entry, I would suggest you structure your sheet so as to only allow data entry via a User Form.  You can then have separate boxes for the integer and decimal parts.

Answer (score 5):

Let each user set their preferred decimal separator for Excel using File > Options > Advanced

[image]

Untick "Use system separator" and set the desired separator symbols. This way User A can use a decimal point with a number, and User B, who prefers decimal comma, can open the same file and will see the same numbers with decimal commas.

Excel is international and can cater to these need. It's just a tick in a box. No VBA required.

Comment: thanks I'm aware of this option, but it presents another problem for user who is sometimes a person which is not so skilled with PC, so I try to make their life easier (making mine harder obviously :) )

Comment: You can use teylyn's method in a macro with a button. In this way the user will only press the button to use the right decimal separator.

Comment: Well, does that user also use the wrong decimal symbol when he uses internet banking?  At some point in time, there will need to be some user education. Why can people happily use online shopping and eBay, but as soon as they enter the office in the morning they seem to lose all computer literacy and need to be spoon fed  the simplest solutions.

Comment: @teylyn you're absolutely right, but try to tell this to your employer.

Comment: @MartinM You mean your employer is happy with the overhead cost that untrained employees create?

Comment: @thilinaR - rolling back the edits. They are insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is the following which works at least back to Excel 2013, but is not supported in Excel 2010.

1. The values are generated. It sounds like you have control, or influence, with that. Have the values generated as Strings, not actual numbers. If coming as actual numbers, wrap the generating formula in the `TEXT` function. It is important to choose a decimal separator and have it for all, or to use a somewhat more complicated approach to tease various separators from the text String generated. Even if you have an integer value, add the separator to it.
2. Next wrap (or use a helper column) the generated values in the `NUMBERVALUE` function. In it, specify as the decimal separator whatever separator you chose for step 1, above. (Notice that your decimal separator for this purpose could be the Greek letter beta rather than a period or comma! `NUMBERVALUE` just cares that it really is and is there.) This fact is why you chose something to use for all, rather than having any of several.
3. Excel then converts the string to a numerical value (or back to one). The important thing here is that the conversion of any given value happens on anyone's machine, or a bunch of them at once if sharing options of various sorts are enabled. But it doesn't matter what their own settings are:  The function converts the standardized Strings to real numbers no matter the machines, and then the individual machines figure out how to display them on their own displays. If two people are looking at the same cell on different machines, one might see a period as the separator and the other a comma.

So you have done an "end run" around the issue. You presented each machine a set of Strings that you have complete control over and fed them into `NUMBERVALUE` using your known separator. The function figured out what the number must be and since none of this so far is dependent upon any particular machine's settings, no one's settings kicked its feet out from under it.

After finishing the number creation process, it's just a number stored in Excel. No separators or whatnot, and Excel does its own thing to display them, unique to each machine, but never actually changing the underlying number, just its presentation.

So, a formula like:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(  GeneratedӚString,  "Ӛ"  )
```

in which the `Ӛ` ("Cyrillic Capital Letter Schwa With Diaresis") character is used as your decimal separator. Of all things. Of course, the comma or period are just fine too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).